# What is best way to structure code for git merging

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

What are some strategies that can be used in code so that it makes it easy to merge changes in git when multiple people are working on the code?

Answer (score 1):

None of strategies can make merge easier, and in common **they doesn't exist**. Manual merge is a job for human

Answer (score 1):

Assign different parts of 'the code' to different people.  Doing so ensures that two people won't be editing the same part (file) and thus avoids all git merge conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lazy Badger. But if you want to make manual merge easier whenever git shows up a conflict, the best thing would be to create relevant topic branches for the developers. Whenever merge conflict happens - the topic branch names should give context to which version should be chosen.

Of course - well commented code for each change will do the same and will probably be better for readability later on.